# Optimizing this 'print up to the nth prime number' script

Tags: python, optimization, algorithm, beginner, primes

I've been seeking to optimize this algorithm, perhaps by eliminating one of the loops, or with a better test to check for prime numbers.

I'm trying to calculate and display 100000 prime numbers has the script pausing for about 6 seconds as it populates the list with primes before the primes list is returned to the console as output.

I've been experimenting with using

```
print odd,
```

to simply print every found prime number, which is faster for smaller inputs like n = 1000, but for n = 1000000 the list itself prints much faster (both in the Python shell and in the console).

Perhaps the entire code/algorithm should be revamped, but the script should remain essentially the same: The user types in the number of prime numbers to be printed (n) and the script returns all prime numbers up to the nth prime number.

```
from time import time
odd = 1
primes = [2]
n = input("Number of prime numbers to print: ")
clock = time()
def isPrime(number):
    global primes
    for i in primes:
        if i*i > number:
            return True
        if number%i is 0:
            return False
while len(primes) < n:
    odd += 2
    if isPrime(odd):
        primes += [odd]
print primes
clock -= time()
print "\n", -clock
raw_input()
```

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes for ideas.

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to programming and code review!

Your code is pretty good especially for a beginner, but I'm going to be picky:

```
from time import time
```

I recommend putting at least one blank line between the imports and the code proper

```
odd = 1
```

You don't use this until much later. Don't declare variables until you actually need them. It will make the code easier to read.

```
primes = [2]
n = input("Number of prime numbers to print: ")
```

Rather than using input, I recommend using int(raw_input(. Input actually interprets the text entered as a python expression which means it can do anything. If you really just wanted a number, using int(raw_input is better. Also, input has been modified in python 3 to be like raw_input.

```
clock = time()
def isPrime(number):
```

Typically functions are defined before the actual code not in the middle of it.

```
    global primes
```

global is only necessary if you want to modify the primes. Since you don't modify it, you don't need it.

```
    for i in primes:
        if i*i > number:
```

It's not immediately obvious why you can stop here. A comment would be helpful.

```
            return True
        if number%i is 0:
```

Put spaces around your operators: %

```
            return False
while len(primes) < n:
    odd += 2
    if isPrime(odd):
        primes += [odd]
```

When adding a single element to a list use primes.append(odd)

```
print primes
clock -= time()
```

That's kinda confusing. I'd suggest doing start_time = .., end_time = ..., time_spent = end_time - start_time. That ways it clear what you are doing, whereas what you've done with the clock is unusual and not immeadiately obvious.

```
print "\n", -clock
raw_input()
```

Also, don't put logic in the top level scope of your program. Put all logic especially loops inside a function. It'll run faster in the function, and will keep the program neater.

Answer (score 0):

To format your code in python is to write it so you have your title/author comments on top, imports below, classes, functions and then your main.

Generally `is` is considered poor coding prose in python mainly because it attracts unnecessary bugs.  `is` compares two objects in memory, == compares their values, with the latter as what coder usually means.

A global variable here is completely unnecessary, there are few cases when it is useful and this is definitely not one of them.  Just send it as an argument.

i*i can be rewritten as i**2

Other than that and what Winston mentioned, very impressive for a beginner.  Keep going!